# error C2662 cannot convert from const to reference

Tags: c++, constants, hashtable

this is my first post on stack overflow, and I hope to join the community in the future.

I'm in the midst of programming a hash table implementation for an ADT class; most of my methods are up to par within the bounds of the assignment, but this is giving me grief.

In this test application which I have been using to test various functions as I write them, I'm recieving the error "error C2662: 'customer::getPhone': cannot convert 'this' ponter from 'const customer' to 'customer &' in reference to the lines 
"cursor = find_ptr(entry.getPhone());"
and 
"list_head_insert(data[hash(entry.getPhone())], entry);"

My code implementation for the functions is as follows:

```
    template <class RecordType>
void table<RecordType>::insert(const RecordType& entry){

    node<RecordType>* cursor;
    cursor = find_ptr(entry.getPhone());

    if(cursor == NULL) {
        list_head_insert(data[hash(entry.getPhone())], entry);
        ++total_records;
    }
    else
        cursor->set_data(entry);

}
```

In this case, getPhone refers to an accessor for an integer private variable, nothing fancy.

Finally, for my main test application:

```
#include "Table2.h"
#include "Customer.h";
using namespace std;

int main () {

    customer myCustomer( "name", "935 street dr.", 5555555 );
    table<customer> myTable;
    cout << myCustomer;

    myTable.insert(myCustomer);


    return 0;
}
```

The frustrating aspect is that this code is used verbatim in both the text, and in several online examples I've looked up after receiving the compilation error; any help would be greatly appreciated, and I would be happy to clarify anything if need be. I am running VS express 2012 for desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessor `RecordType::getPhone()` needs to be declared `const`.

Comment: Oddly enough I've tried changing coding the accessor as a constant, but it still yields the same result.

const int getPhone() {return customerPhoneNumber;};

Comment: You need to to put the `const` after the function, as in your answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This was purely a syntactic error on my part. In my sleep deprived silliness I typed:

```
Const int getPhone() {return customerPhoneNumber;};
```

instead of

```
int getPhone() const {return customerPhoneNumber;};
```

foolishness